# How to identify if a table has been changed in Greenplum?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greenplum

We have a process that takes two tables as inputs. Here is my scenario.. When process is run, I need to know if the data in two input tables have been changed (insert or update or truncate or delete) from what it was during previous execution to determine the further course of action within the process. Basically this is one of my criteria to determine if the run is a fresh run or a run after a failure of the process.

One way I could think is by taking backup of the input tables when the process is run, and compare it with the input using EXCEPT statement during next run, and remove the backed up tables when the process gets completed successfully. But I am looking for something more elegant.

Another way I thought is by capturing time stamp using triggers do something based on it. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible to execute queries using triggers in Greenplum. I will have to add time stamp column on the same table on which I add the trigger. I am not keen on doing that as input tables are controlled by users of the process and not by the developer. If the process fails after adding a new time stamp column for some reason, it may surprise the users (from business).

Any suggestions on efficient ways to capture this table change information in Greenplum? I am using PostgrSQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum doesn't support triggers so that proposed solution won't work.

How about you log your activity to a table or a file for each process execution?